# JPA Repository - one to many - issue with removing one child

Tags: java, jpa, repository, one-to-many

I have a one to many relationship between Father and Son. I am working with JPA Repository.
If I delete a son with id 54 and then get all the sons again :

```
sonRepository.delete(id);   
List<Son> sons = sonRepository.findAll();
```

I am getting this error :

> javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find
>   com.myapp.domain.Son with id 54

My entities :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_FATHER")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class FAther implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "father", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Son> sons = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<Son> getSons() {
        return sons;
    }

    public void setSons(Set<Son> sons) {
        this.sons = sons;
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "T_SON")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Son implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Father father;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Father getFather() {
        return father;
    }

    public void setFather(Father father) {
        this.father = father;
    }
}
```

This error seems to happen only when the son is already in database or inserted in database via sql (not with the application). If the son is added via the application :

```
sonRepository.save(son);
```

I don't have any problem. The problem happens again if I restart the server. It 's like the problem appears if the addSon and deleteSon are not done in the same session (same server instance).

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. If someone can help me on this...

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to remove the cache?

Comment: which cache are you talking about? like a flush?

Comment: The lines with `@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)`...

Comment: Your solution worked well. Can't figure out why, because the cache works for other similar one to many entities in my application. Thanks

Comment: I have posted an answer. Could you report it to Spring, in which case you could drop the URL to the question here in comments? Also may be updating spring to the next version could help, did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a bug to me in the caching mechanism. I would report it to Spring. As a working workaround the OP confirmed the removing `@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)`.